# What is replcement for "WebPanel" in infragistics 15.1

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I am upgrading infragistics version 2010.1 to 2015.1. I couldn't find WebPanel in "Infragistics.WebUI.Misc"(in infragistics 2015.1 version) where as in infragistics 2010.1 its in "Infragistics.WebUI.Misc". If WebPanel is retired after 2010.1version  then what is the replacement for it in 2015.1?

Answer (score -1):

The following information came from:
https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/111252.aspx

`WebPanel` control in infragistics 2010.1 version was replaced with `WebExplorerBar` which is in the `Infragistics.Web.UI.NavigationControls` namespace.